# Store X509AttributeCertificateHolder object, especially attrCert local and open it

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, attributecertificate

There is an option to store the `X509Certificate` local with the class `JcaPEMWriter` from the Bouncy Castle API. After storing the `X509Certificate` I can open it with `openssl` with the following command:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text
```

I have the following code:

```
X509AttributeCertificateHolder att = acBuilder.build(new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1WithRSA").setProvider("BC").build(caprivkey));
```

Now I want to store the *attrCert* (the Attribute Certificate) local, which is contained in the `att` variable. How can I do this? And how can I open the *attrCert*, it is possible to open it with `openssl` or any other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save your Attribute Certificate in a PEM file, you can use `JcaPEMWriter` as well:

```java
// save the Attribute Certificate to attcert.pem file
JcaPEMWriter writer = new JcaPEMWriter(new FileWriter("attcert.pem"));
writer.writeObject(att);
writer.close();
```

The file will contain a base64 content, like this:

```
-----BEGIN ATTRIBUTE CERTIFICATE-----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-----END ATTRIBUTE CERTIFICATE-----
```

Unfortunately, it seems that there's no specific command in `openssl` to check the Attribute Certificate (check [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.openssl.users/KPI2eg_mLq4) and [this message with no replies](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2016-October/004644.html) - there's an [extended version of `openssl`](http://www.lcc.uma.es/~monte/OpenPMI/) that seems to support it, although I haven't tested it).

But you can check the ASN.1 structure using the `asn1parse` option:

```
openssl asn1parse -dump -i -in attcert.pem
```

The output will be the ASN.1 structure, like this:

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 447 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 296 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim:   INTEGER           :01
   11:d=2  hl=2 l= 103 cons:   SEQUENCE          
   13:d=3  hl=2 l= 101 cons:    cont [ 0 ]        
   15:d=4  hl=2 l=  96 cons:     SEQUENCE          
   17:d=5  hl=2 l=  94 cons:      cont [ 4 ]        
   19:d=6  hl=2 l=  92 cons:       SEQUENCE          
   21:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET               
   23:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons:         SEQUENCE          
   25:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :countryName
   30:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :AU
   34:d=7  hl=2 l=  40 cons:        SET               
   36:d=8  hl=2 l=  38 cons:         SEQUENCE          
   38:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationName
   43:d=9  hl=2 l=  31 prim:          UTF8STRING        :The Legion of the Bouncy Castle
... and so on
```

Or you can read the file using Bouncy Castle:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509AttributeCertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

String pem = // read contents from PEM file
// Convert to AC object
byte[] data = Base64.decode(pem.getBytes());
X509AttributeCertificateHolder holder = new X509AttributeCertificateHolder(data);
```